# Android 13 configuration stops on picking screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, encryption, unbricking, pattern-lock

**tl;dr** *My phone has become "bricked". After wiping all the data it regain normal functionality, but I cannot complete Android initial configuration due to phone stopping on selection of a screen lock.*

*Am I correct that this is due to malfunctioning encryption chip or key store? That caused Android to not being able to read encrypted data in first place (when becoming a brick). And then to encrypt it again (after reinitializing Android)?*

---

Suddenly, out of nowhere (while resting in a pocket), my Redmi 11S has become a perfect brick. Unable to do anything except running over and over again into recovery mode. No option, except "Wipe Data", no solution found in the Internet worked.

I used "Wipe Data" and phone has become again operational. It went through all the steps of initial Android configuration and stopped completely on selecting screen lock security element.

No matter what I pick (password, PIN or pattern), I provide it for the second time (to verify), I tap next and phone stops there with nothing happening for the next many hours. It isn't hanged, I can always go back and select another screen lock solution, but I always hit the wall and phone does not continue after verification.

Since Redme 11S / Android 13 doesn't allow to have no screen lock at all, I cannot continue with installation / configuration of Android and phone is pretty much useless.

Am I correct that electronic chip that is responsible for encrypting data or key store has died in this phone?

My assumptions:

1. Dead encryption chip or key store caused phone to reset in first time and being unable to read (unencrypt) data and start Android in the first place.
2. No recovery option or solution could work, because all the unencrypted data in storage was seen as a total garbage
3. Wiping data removed that garbage and allowed Android to start, but it hangs on selecting screen lock, because it is unable to encrypt data due to malfunctioning encryption chip / key store / encryption solution.

Is the above somewhere near possibility? Or is it a complete false shot?

I am going to ship this phone to the repair shop, but I want to be able to tell them something else then just dully "I can't select screen lock pattern".

Comment: Special security hardware is not used often on Android (Google and may be Samsung have one). But the common way to implement security bases on ARM TrustZone (TEE) a special virtual mini system that also uses the main CPU. Anyway security and file encryption should be already active when you reach lock screen config option.

Comment: Thank you! So my assumptions are wrong. Thanks for claryfing.